# How to convert milliseconds to “mmm:ss” format?

Tags: java, android

I have made class which display result in `mmm:ss` format

**Below is the code:**

```
class CountDown extends CountDownTimer {

    public CountDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long ms = millisUntilFinished;
        String text = String.format("%03d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(ms) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(ms)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(ms) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(ms)));
        tvTimer.setText(text);
    }


    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        try {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MCQActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Time is over")
                    .setMessage("Your time is finished, Click on ok to go result page")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            saveWorkAndShowResult();

                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If I am passing

```
mCountDownTimer = new CountDown(1000 * 60 * 30, 1000);
mCountDownTimer.start();
```

It is working fine and showing me `30 mins`

But if I want to show `180 min`

```
mCountDownTimer = new CountDown(1000 * 60 * 180, 1000);
```

It is starting from `60 min`

Can anybody help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Probably because there is no "hour part" in your formatting

Comment: @RC. thanks for your suggestion will you please help me how to resolve this

Comment: With "raw" computation: https://ideone.com/Aa02CG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code reduces to the amount of minutes, excluding any hours, Simply remove the bit that says `- TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(ms)` to fix this

Answer (score 0):

You may use below convert function(s) in your code ;

```
        Long hour = TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(millisUntilFinished, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        millisUntilFinished= millisUntilFinished% (1000 * 60 * 60);
        Long minutes = TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(millisUntilFinished, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        millisUntilFinished= millisUntilFinished% (1000 * 60);
        Long seconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(millisUntilFinished, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        millisUntilFinished= millisUntilFinished% 1000;
        Long milisec = millisUntilFinished;
```

then just past to variable your String formatter ;

```
        String text = String.format("%03d:%02d", minutes , seconds );
```

Answer (score 0):

var date = new Date($('#date').val());
 date.setTime(date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);